# Finding orthogonal basis with constraint

Tags: algorithms, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

Is there any fast algorithm that output an orthogonal basis $e_i,i\leq n$ of $R^n$
with $e_i\in V_i$? Where $V_i,i\leq n$ are given linear subspaces of $R^n$.

And is there any condition on $V_i,i\leq n$ that garantee the solution? (A somewhat trivial condition could be $dim V_i \geq i$)

This is equivalent to solving a group of quadratic and linear equations. But is there other faster algorithm?